# Would creating 250 HTML pages slow down my website?

Tags: html, wordpress, performance, optimization, web

Pretty simple question, I'm not very experienced with websites ect... And I would just like to know if I were to create 250 HTML pages to add content to on my website, would it slow it down at all?
Thanks!

Comment: A website with 250 pages is extremely small. Even if you had 25,000 pages the user views only one of them at a time so it wouldn't make any difference. The only possible slowdown would be from Wordpress making the database query to fetch the page, but with only 250 records the query would be practically instantaneous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the number of web pages won't slow down the site.

The cause of slowness is generally more about how many pages are being delivered concurrently (particularly if the pages are generated dynamically with each request, as is the case in WordPress without a caching plugin).